# How to add a custom Image component to Sitecore Experience Editor, within a Tab?

Tags: sxa, sxa-storefront

This is my View:

```
<div>
     @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image Field")
</div>
```

When I add this rendering to my Page in Sitecore SXA, it works perfectly, allowing the user to click on the image and edit it.

If I drop this rendering onto a tab, it stops working. Can anyone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this:

@Html.Sitecore().Field(PracticeAreas.Products.ProductImage, Sitecore.Context.Item)

Comment: The field renderer uses the datasource and if no datasource is set the context item to render a field. It seems like that in your case the datasource of the tab is used instead of the context item. If you are sure, that you always want to use the context item, you are on the right track.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. Sometimes it takes some time until you are able to do it. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/